# Saving values from a http post from a nested resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am trying to use a nested resource in rails to create a new record. I am attempting to use of `/events/id/entries/new` where there is a

```
<%= form_for([@event, @entry]) do |f| %>
```

on the new page.

My models are:

```
class Entry < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :event

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :entries, dependent: :destroy

class Event < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :entries, dependent: :destroy
```

The controller is:

```
def new
  @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
  @entry = @event.entries.build
end

def create
  @user = current_user
  @entry = Entry.new(user_id: @user.id, event_id: :event_id , course: :entry.course , siCard: :entry.siCard)
  if @entry.save
    redirect_to @user
    flash.now[:info] = "Event Created"
  else
    render '/create'
    flash.now[:danger] = "Somthing went wrong"
  end
end
```

But the record does not save `NoMethodError in EntriesController#create`despite it saying that the parameters passed are.

```
"utf8"=>"✓",
"entry"=>{"course"=>"Orange", "siCard"=>"23232323"},
"commit"=>"Enter",
"event_id"=>"2"}
```

How do I modify the create controller to save the record?

Comment: Generally, it is good practice to include more of your stack trace to help folks help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a go:

```
@entry = Entry.new(
  user_id:  current_user.id, 
  event_id: params[:event_id], 
  course:   params[:entry][:course], 
  siCard:   params[:entry][:siCard]
)
```

You don't need to `@user = current_user`, just use `current_user.id`.

`event_id: :event_id` is just going to set `event_id` to a symbol. You want to access the params value, I am guessing. So:

```
event_id: params[:event_id]
```

Here:

```
course: :entry.course
```

you're trying to call the `course` method on the `:entry` symbol. What?!?

Instead:

```
course: params[:entry][:course]
```

Same thing with `siCard`.

BTW, `siCard` is not very Ruby-ish. Rather, you should do `si_card`.

Comment: Do you have any recomended books for learning ruby and rails correctly?

Comment: Like many people, I started with Michael Hartl's [tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book). [Programming Ruby](https://pragprog.com/book/ruby/programming-ruby) is also popular. There are many other good books and tutorial, too many to mention.